# NullPointerException occurred in parsing ListView item to setBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I have received a `NullPointerException` in my `ListView` item while calling `setBackgroundResource` on it.

Initially I've a list of items that display well and when user click on those list items basically it is `OnClickListener`, they will change the background color immediately. But what I wanted to do now is when I have to change the background color of some of the items `onCreate` but not waiting for users to click on the item. The line complained is on the line to `setBackgroundResource()`.

Please kindly help me with this problem. Thank you. Below is my code.

```
    private ArrayList<String> initialfetch = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listlayout); 

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list );
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, contactlist);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


       // get Intent from the previous calling activity
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String identifier = intent.getStringExtra("identifier");
       String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

       if(identifier.equals("edit"))
       { // model.Static_Activity.event_list is tested to pass the correct position of item into the list
        for(int i = 0; i < model.Static_Activity.event_list.get(Integer.parseInt(position)).getAttendees().size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < initialfetch.size(); j++)
            {
                if(initialfetch.get(j).equals(model.Static_Activity.event_list.get(Integer.parseInt(position)).getAttendees().get(i)))
                {   // Problems happened on this line
                    ((View) ((ListView) mainListView.getChildAt(j)).getAdapter()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_2);

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

$Edited Post: Below is my stack trace file and line 66 is the setBackGroundResource line:

```
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialeventplanner/view.Select_Attendees}:         java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         view.Select_Attendees.onCreate(Select_Attendees.java:66)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    08-22 06:35:32.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Please share the stack trace. It must have the line number where the exception is occurring.

Comment: btw the Resources xml files are all tested to be working fine since I have been using the same code and get it works onItemClick()

Comment: all right. will edit my post now. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: At which line you got error?

Comment: ((View) ((ListView) mainListView.getChildAt(j)).getAdapter()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_2);

Comment: The line above causes the problem. If I change to mainListView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_2); it works properly. But it is not what I wanted to do. This is just a test about the child item doesn't being defined that's why I got the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getChildAt()` on just created ListView, and it doesn't have children yet. Also note that if the user scrolls ListView up or down, its views are recycled so basically only the views exist that are in sight.

Also even if you didn't get NPE you woud get ClassCastException when trying to convert `ArrayAdapter` returned from `getAdapter()` to `View`. `getAdapter` call is not needed here at all.

What you really should do is to create a custom adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MyAdapter() {
        super(MyActivity.this, R.layout.simplerow, contactlist);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (some_condition)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_2);

        return v;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    listAdapter = new MyAdapter();
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    ...
    // remove your setBackgroundResource code from here
}
```

Comment: This is actually the one that solves the item not yet initialized problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw does the method getView being called for every row of elements from the list? cuz now my problem is it actually not only colors the background of the selected item in the list but all items.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got this error because that view yet not created. When you create a `ListView`, then all the rows of the list are not created at the same time. When you will scrolling up then remaining rows of the list will be created.

If you want to modify your listview you can update your `contactlist`.

And then call  `<your adpter object>.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Yea I think the rows of the list are not created and when I access it, it causes null pointer. So how can I solved this problem?

Comment: If you want to modify your listview you can update your "contactlist". and then call .notifyDataSetChanged();  This will update your listview information.

Answer (score 0):

Any object in the following chain:

```
((View) ((ListView) mainListView.getChildAt(j)).getAdapter()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_2);
```

is a candidate for the NPE: it could be `mainListView` or `mainListView.getChildAt(j)` (for one of the `j`s) etc.

Debug your code to find which one id the object that you expect to be there but is actually missing/undefined.

Comment: It's the child item that causes this problem. So how should I get the child being defined before I actually access the real item view of it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better to customize the [**`Adapter`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and inside ***public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)*** setBackgroundResource on `ImageView` depending on condition.

---

### Tutorials for listview with custom adapter

1. [ListView with custom adapter from vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
2. [Tutorial 2](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)
3. [Tutorial 3](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html)
4. [Tutorial 4](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)